# Emmet for <%= %> in EEX files with Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'd like to know if there is an emmet to generate `<%= %>` into eex html files with Phoenix. I have the Elixir Extension with VS Code.

Comment: It looks like you can create your own snippets. Why not do that?

Comment: Sure I know it is possible but I want to know if there is some kind of convention or an emmet already done.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using emacs just get [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) and write this in `~/.doom.d/snippets/web-mode/eextag`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: eex tag
# key: et
# condition: t
# --
<%= $0 %>
```

trigger with `et`+`tab`